# Tangent to a graph through an exterior point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, tangent-line

Say you are given $f(x) = 5x^2$ and you want to find a tangent line to $f$ that goes through $P(0|-10)$.

The two options you have is using the tangent line equation, $t(x) = f'(a) \cdot (x - a) + f(a)$ and the point slope form, $t(x_1) - t(x_2) = m(x_1 - x_2)$.

Both lead to $$t(x) = 10\sqrt{2}x - 10$$ and $$t(x) = -10\sqrt{2}x - 10$$ after setting $t(0) = -10$.

Now, is there a way to find these by using $t(x) = mx + k$? You could use that without any problems if the point was on the graph of f, but here, it seems like you will have:
$$t(x) = mx + k$$ now $m$ = $f'(a)$ where $a$ is the x-coordinate of the point that touches $f$
$$t(x) = 10ax + k$$
$$t(0) = -10 \implies k = -10$$
$$\implies t(x) = 10ax - 10$$

From here on, we would need to find $a$, but we can't set $t(0) = -10$ again because that would just give a true statement.

So it seems like you can't use $t(x) = mx + k$ here.

> Q: Now, how to notice when you can use $t(x) = mx + k$ and when you cannot, without having to try?
>
> Is the case where the point isn't on the graph of $f$ an exception and you can use $t(x) = mx + k$ everywhere else?

Comment: Joachimsthal or $s \cdot s_{11}=s_1^2$ gives both tangents in one fell swoop: $(y-5x^2)(-10-5\cdot 0^2)=((y-10)/2-5x\cdot 0)^2.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a tangent line $t(x) = mx + k$ to the graph of the function $f(x) = 5x^2$ passes through the point $(0, -10)$, then it must also pass through the point $(x, 5x^2)$.  Hence,
$$5x^2 = mx - 10$$
which can be expressed as the quadratic equation
$$5x^2 - mx + 10 = 0$$
If a line is tangent to a curve, then it intersects the curve at a single point in a neighborhood of the point of tangency, which occurs when the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ is equal to zero.
\begin{align*}
\Delta & = 0\\
(-m)^2 - 4(5)(10) & = 0\\
m^2 - 200 & = 0\\
m^2 & = 200\\
|m| & = \sqrt{200}\\
|m| & = 10\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
Hence, $m = 10\sqrt{2}$ or $m = -10\sqrt{2}$.  Thus, the two tangent lines to the curve $f(x) = 5x^2$ that pass through the point $(0, -10)$ are $y = 10\sqrt{2}x - 10$ and $y = -10\sqrt{2}x - 10$.

Comment: Thank you, but
"If a tangent line $t(x)=mx+k$ to the graph of the function $f(x)=5x^2$ passes through the point $(0,−10)$, then it must also pass through the point $(x,5x^2)$"

Why is this?

Comment: The curve is $y = 5x^2$.  The tangent line to the curve $y = 5x^2$ must intersect the curve $y = 5x^2$ at one point, so it passes through both the point $(0, -10)$ and the point $(x, 5x^2)$.

Comment: Oh, thank you.

Why does the intersection occur when the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ is $0$?

Comment: In order for the tangent line to intersect the curve in one point, the quadratic equation must have a double root, which occurs when the discriminant is equal to zero since the roots are $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. $\\$